# How did Eurovision handle countries without a de jure official language?

Tags: international

At some stages of its history, the Eurovision Song Contest had restrictions on what languages could be sung by a given country.

However, it seems that countries that lacked a de jure official language, such as the United Kingdom, were still able to compete.

What were the exact restrictions Eurovision had on languages, and how did it handle countries without a de jure official language.

Comment: There isn't a single official language in Belgium, and in the relevant period their entries were in French, Dutch and English: English isn't anywhere official in Belgium. In Switzerland they've used all of the locally-official languages. Apparently in 1991 Italy used Neapolitan which is not at all official, but perhaps the overseers thought it was Italian.